# Impossible to generate my fixtures alice hautelook symfony Neither the property "productType" nor one of the methods "getProductType()"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, fixtures

I can't not generate fixtures in my symfony project.
Previoucly, I had a attribute OnetoMany and i passed to ManytoMany.
I think that error comes from here.

I generate my fixtures with alice fixtures bundle : https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle

I use this commande :

```
./bin/console hautelook:fixtures:load --no-interaction --purge-with-truncate
```

This result :

```
  Neither the property "productType" nor one of the methods "getProductType()", "productType()", "isProductType()", "hasProductType()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Product".
```

My concerned entity :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Annotation\Cached;
use App\Traits\ContentEntityTrait;
use App\Traits\SeoTrait;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinTable;
use Exception;
use JsonSerializable;
use Serializable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Class Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 *
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @Cached()
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 */
class Product implements Serializable, JsonSerializable
{
    use ContentEntityTrait;
    use SeoTrait;

    //<editor-fold desc="Members">

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $packaging;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $packing;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $gencod;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_picture", fileNameProperty="picture")
     *
     * @Assert\Image(mimeTypes = {
     *          "image/png",
     *          "image/jpeg",
     *          "image/jpg",
     *      })
     *
     * @var File
     */
    protected $pictureFile;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\Length(max=100)
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $picture;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $pdf;

    /**
     * @var File
     *
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"})
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_pdf", fileNameProperty="pdf")
     */
    protected $pdfFile;

    /**
     * @var Brand
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Brand", inversedBy="products")
     */
    protected $brand;

    /**
     * @var Collection|ProductType[]
     * @Assert\Count(min=1, minMessage="Il faut sélectionner au moins {{ limit }} élément")
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="products")
     * @JoinTable(name="product_product_type")
     */
    protected $productTypes;

    /**
     * @var Collection|Sector[]
     *
     * @Assert\Count(min=1, minMessage="Il faut sélectionner au moins {{ limit }} élément")
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Sector")
     */
    protected $sectors;

    /**
     * @var GemRcn[]
     *
     * @Assert\Count(min=1, minMessage="Il faut sélectionner au moins {{ limit }} élément")
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\GemRcn", inversedBy="products")
     */
    protected $gemRcns;

    /**
     * @var Collection|Sample[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Sample", mappedBy="product", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $samples;

    /**
     * @var Collection|Product[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product")
     */
    protected $products;

    /**
     * @var Collection|Inspiration[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Inspiration")
     */
    protected $inspirations;
    /**
     * @var Collection|Product[]
     * Many Product have many Product.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_scoring",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="current_product", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="next_product", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $scoring;

    /**
     * @var User[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="products")
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default": true})
     */
    protected $enabled = true;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * Field not mapped
     */
    protected $favorite = false;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * Field not mapped
     */
    protected $picturePath;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * Field not mapped
     */
    protected $previewPath;

    //</editor-fold>

    /**
     * Product constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sectors   = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->productTypes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->samples   = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->products  = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->users     = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->gemRcns   = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->scoring   = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function toggleUser(User $user): bool
    {
        if ($this->isFavorite($user)) {
            $this->removeUser($user);

            return false;
        }

        $this->addUser($user);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isFavorite(?User $user): bool
    {
        return $this->users->contains($user);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function jsonSerialize(): array
    {
        return [
            'id'          => $this->id,
            'title'       => $this->title,
            'slug'        => $this->slug,
            'packaging'   => $this->packaging,
            'brand'       => $this->brand->__toString(),
            'isFavorite'  => $this->favorite,
            'picturePath' => $this->picturePath,
            'previewPath' => $this->previewPath,
            'picture' => $this->picture
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->title,
            $this->slug,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->title,
            $this->slug,
            ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => true]);
    }

    //<editor-fold desc="Getters">

    /**
     * @return null|File
     */
    public function getPictureFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->pictureFile;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getPicture(): ?string
    {
        return $this->picture;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPdf(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pdf;
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getPdfFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->pdfFile;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPackaging(): ?string
    {
        return $this->packaging;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPacking(): ?string
    {
        return $this->packing;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGencod(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gencod;
    }

    /**
     * @return Brand
     */
    public function getBrand(): ?Brand
    {
        return $this->brand;
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductType[]|Collection
     */
    public function getProductTypes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->productTypes;
    }

    /**
     * @return Sector[]|Collection
     */
    public function getSectors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sectors;
    }

    /**
     * @return Product[]|Collection
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @return GemRcn[]|Collection
     */
    public function getGemRcns(): Collection
    {
        return $this->gemRcns;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold desc="Setters">
    /**
     * @param string $picture
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public function setPicture(?string $picture): self
    {
        $this->picture = $picture;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param File $pictureFile
     *
     * @return static
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function setPictureFile(?File $pictureFile): self
    {
        $this->pictureFile = $pictureFile;
        if ($pictureFile instanceof UploadedFile && $pictureFile->getError() === 0) {
            $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $pdf
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPdf(?string $pdf): self
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param File $pdfFile
     *
     * @return self
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function setPdfFile(?File $pdfFile): self
    {
        $this->pdfFile = $pdfFile;
        if ($pdfFile instanceof UploadedFile && $pdfFile->getError() === 0) {
            $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $packaging
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPackaging(string $packaging): self
    {
        $this->packaging = $packaging;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $packing
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPacking(string $packing): self
    {
        $this->packing = $packing;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $gencod
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setGencod(string $gencod): self
    {
        $this->gencod = $gencod;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Brand $brand
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setBrand(Brand $brand): self
    {
        $this->brand = $brand;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductType $productType
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function addProductType(ProductType $productType): self
    {
        $this->productTypes->add($productType);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $enabled
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setEnabled(bool $enabled): self
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $isFavorite
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setFavorite(bool $isFavorite): self
    {
        $this->favorite = $isFavorite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $path
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPicturePath(string $path): self
    {
        $this->picturePath = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $path
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPreviewPath(string $path): self
    {
        $this->previewPath = $path;

        return $this;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold desc="Collection">
    /**
     * @param Sector $sector
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeSector(Sector $sector): self
    {
        $this->sectors->removeElement($sector);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductType $productType
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeProductType(ProductType $productType): self
    {
        $this->productTypes->removeElement($productType);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Sector $sector
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function addSector(Sector $sector): self
    {
        $this->sectors->add($sector);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Sample $sample
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeSample(Sample $sample): self
    {
        $this->samples->removeElement($sample);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Sample $sample
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function addSample(Sample $sample): self
    {
        $this->samples->add($sample);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        $this->products->add($product);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        $this->users->add($user);
        $user->addProduct($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
        $user->removeProduct($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param GemRcn $gemRcn
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function addGemRcn(GemRcn $gemRcn): self
    {
        $this->gemRcns->add($gemRcn);
        $gemRcn->addProduct($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param GemRcn $gemRcn
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeGemRcn(GemRcn $gemRcn): self
    {
        $this->gemRcns->removeElement($gemRcn);
        $gemRcn->removeProduct($this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getScoring(){
        return $this->scoring;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addScoring(Product $product) :self
    {
        $this->scoring->add($product);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeScoring(Product $product): self
    {
        $this->scoring->removeElement($product);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

My other entity (ManytoMany) :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Annotation\Cached;
use App\Traits\ContentEntityTrait;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;



/**
 * Class ProductType
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductTypeRepository")
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"title", "universe"})
 *
 * @Cached()
 */
class ProductType implements \JsonSerializable
{
    use ContentEntityTrait;

    //<editor-fold desc="Members">
    /**
     * @var Universe
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Universe", inversedBy="productTypes", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $universe;

    /**
     * @var Product[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="productTypes", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $products;
    //</editor-fold>

    /**
     * Product Type constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function jsonSerialize(): array
    {
        return [
            'id'    => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
        ];
    }

    //<editor-fold desc="Getters">

    /**
     * @return Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @return Universe
     */
    public function getUniverse(): ?Universe
    {
        return $this->universe;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold desc="Setters">
    /**
     * @param Universe $universe
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setUniverse(Universe $universe): self
    {
        $this->universe = $universe;
        $universe->addProductType($this);

        return $this;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold desc="Collection">
    /**
     * @param Product $product
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        $this->products->add($product);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);

        return $this;
    }


    //</editor-fold>
}
```

My fixtures yaml :

```
App\Entity\Product:
    product_{1..40}:
        title: '<sentence(3)>'
        description: '<sentence()>'
        packaging: '<sentence(3)>'
        packing: '<sentence(3)>'
        picture: '<fileCopy("features/files/image/test-picture.jpg","public/uploads/products", 0)>'
        brand: '@brand_<numberBetween(1, 10)>'
        gemRcns: ['@gem_rcn_<numberBetween(1, 10)>']
        gencod: '<sentence(3)>'
        productTypes: ['@product_type_<numberBetween(1, 21)>','@product_type_<numberBetween(1, 21)>']
        sectors: ['@school', '@health' ,'@pension', '@company', '@bakery', '@hostel', '@retailer']
```

Comment: well, the error message *is* correct. I would suggest to first clear the caches, in case you changed your pluralization in either the entity or the fixture, and if that doesn't help either, you might want to use the support channels of that alice bundle

Comment: I have already regenerated several times ...
Thank you

Comment: How did you clear the cache? using CLI command? If yes. Try to remove the var/cache folder and try again

Comment: I have used both but the error always comes back